# NFSv4 permissions issues with an exported glusterfs

Tags: nfs4

I have a situation with kernel NFS server. I have two exports with exactly the same ACLs, with full permissions for the informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx group. One is /exports/directo_informatica/, which is the mount point for an LV with XFS, and the other is /exports/gv0_inf/, which is the mount point for a glusterfs. The first export works right when mounting it remotely with NFS, and accessing it with a user of the group informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx. The second one doesn't: it can be mounted correctly, but when trying to access it with the same user it gives "Permission denied".

If I access directly to the NFS server (ssh) with the same user of the previous tests, I can access both directories inside /exports/ without problems. More details at following:

OS: Rocky Linux release 8.5 (Green Obsidian)

fstab for the exported directories:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_kvm_sistema-lv_directo_informatica /exports/directo_informatica xfs defaults 0 0
glustersrv02.xx.xx.xx:/gv0_inf /exports/gv0_inf/ glusterfs defaults,acl 0 0
```

Mount for the exported directories:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_kvm_sistema-lv_directo_informatica on /exports/directo_informatica type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
glustersrv02.xx.xx.xx:/gv0_inf on /exports/gv0_inf type fuse.glusterfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,max_read=131072)
```

exports file:

```
/exports          *(sec=krb5p,secure,rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,root_squash,fsid=0)
/exports/directo_informatica  *(sec=krb5p,secure,rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,root_squash,mountpoint)
/exports/gv0_inf  *(sec=krb5p,secure,rw,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,root_squash,mountpoint,fsid=2)
```

Exported directories ACLs:

```
# getfacl /exports/directo_informatica/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: exports/directo_informatica/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
group::r-x
group:root:r-x
group:informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:root:r-x
default:group:informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

# getfacl /exports/gv0_inf/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: exports/gv0_inf/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
group::r-x
group:root:r-x
group:informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:root:r-x
default:group:informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Directories mounted remoteley:

```
gluster02.adtest.xx.xx.xx:/directo_informatica on /prueba2 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=krb5p,clientaddr=10.2.100.8,local_lock=none,addr=10.2.100.8)
gluster02.adtest.xx.xx.xx:/gv0_inf on /prueba type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=krb5p,clientaddr=10.2.100.8,local_lock=none,addr=10.2.100.8)
```

NFSv4 ACLs remotely:

```
$ nfs4_getfacl /prueba2
# file: /prueba2
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A::root@idmpru.fnr.gub.uy:rwaDxtcy
A::GROUP@:rxtcy
A:g:root@idmpru.fnr.gub.uy:rxtcy
A:g:informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx@idmpru.xx.xx.xx:rwaDxtcy
A::EVERYONE@:tcy
A:fdi:OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A:fdi:root@idmpru.xx.xx.xx:rwaDxtcy
A:fdi:GROUP@:rxtcy
A:fdig:root@idmpru.xx.xx.xx:rxtcy
A:fdig:informatica@adtest.xx.xx.xx@idmpru.xx.xx.xx:rwaDxtcy
A:fdi:EVERYONE@:tcy

$ nfs4_getfacl /prueba
# file: /prueba
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
A::GROUP@:rwaDxtcy
A::EVERYONE@:tcy
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this one. The details: https://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-devel/2022-March/057802.html.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).